# Wife’s clothing in islam

Tags: husband-wife, clothing, wife

A wife is supposed to wear what her husband wishes if I am not wrong so my question is that if the husband wants his wife to wear tight, seethrough or short clothes in public can she wear it or not

Comment: Islam says women cannot wear tight/see-through/short clothes in public which expose their Awrah/body. The husband has no right to tell his wife to do something against Islam and in that case, there is no obligation on her to obey him. So she should not do so.

Comment: Why would a husband want her wife to appear promiscuous in public?

Answer (score 1):

**No**

To start with the phrase,

> A wife is supposed to wear what her husband wishes

If your husband is following the Sunnah of our Islam, then definitely he won't be asking you about this request.

According to our Hadith and Holy Quran, a Husband can **ask** his wife to wear whatever he wants, provided it should be in private and within our Shariah laws.
Also if the wife is not comfortable, then she can tell him the same.

Note the Keyword **ASK** has been written.

But to be in Public, it should be something to which body parts can't be visible or seen through or the structure of different body parts can be notified.

So, my dear sister, you should inform your husband of the same, so that he can understand it in a better way.

Comment: The husband has a legal right to obedience in halal matters, he isn't limited to merely asking.

Comment: @G.Bach Indeed, besides asking for wishes, he must know beforehand the Sunnah of our Islam, and the ways to ask for some favor. If by any chance he is unaware of the fact/situation, its the other person duty to get him informed.

Comment: "and the ways to ask for some favor." He wouldn't be asking for a favor, he would be demanding his **legal right**. If she doesn't obey him in halal matters, there are **legal** repercussions for her.

Comment: @G.Bach which legal rights are you taking. Here the reference is for wearing see through clothes. Wearing these types of clothes is strictly prohibited in Islam, my friend. And any husband can't force to wear the same in public acc to Islamic way. Hope you got my point.

Answer (score -3):

"There is no obedience to the creation if it means disobeying the Creator".

I consider myself a very reformist and left leaning Muslim and I really think the laws of women's clothing need to be reinterpreted for Muslims living in 21st century (for example I don't think sisters should be covered completely in burqahs, unless they really want to be).

But at the same time I do believe the Quran encourages modesty in clothing and in that regard any dress which reveals a woman's body too much (such as the types you mentioned, tight, see through and short) cannot be encouraged.

At the same time, just like the laws of clothing need to be revisited, I think so do the laws regarding husband and wife relationships.

My dear sister, you seem to think it is an obligation on you to dress how your husband commands. I am not sure that is from Islam either. I don't think Islam commands blind obedience to the point where a wife becomes like a servant.

But I also advice you to be patient with your husband, because even if there is no blind obedience, the wife is commanded to please her husband just as the husband is commanded to please his wife. The more that we give for the other, the more we will be given by our Creator.

But if he is commanding you to something clearly haram, I would refer back to the maxim with which I opened this answer and Allah Knows best.